# Parse custom tag in html file using powershell

Tags: html, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a custom html file, with the below code with custom tag "TBD:comment". I want to get content from this tag.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<h1> This is a heading </h1>
<P id='para1'>First Paragraph with some Random text</P>
<P>Second paragraph with more random text</P>
<A href="http://Geekeefy.wordpress.com">Cool Powershell blog</A>
<TBD:comment name="Title"><h3>Katamma katamma loge kathamma</h3> 
</TBD:comment>
<TBD:comment name="content"><h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unk</h3> </TBD:comment>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

---

The below code does not seem to work with the custom tag.

```
enter code here
$html = Get-Content "C:\Users\sahuBaba\Desktop\ht.html" -Raw
$doc = New-Object -com "HTMLFILE"
$doc.IHTMLDocument2_write($html)

$text = $doc.body.getElementsByTagName("TBD:comment")
"Inner Text: " + $text[1].innerText
```

no output. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try with regex:

```
$regex = New-Object Text.RegularExpressions.Regex "<TBD:comment.+?(>.+?)<\/TBD:comment>", ('singleline', 'multiline')
$content = "<your html>"
foreach($m in $regex.Matches($content)) {
    # remove leading '<'
    $m.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. it works, one small follow up question if i want to get down for a specific name for the same tag <TBD:comment name="Body[0].BodySection">. if you can help me to get that as well. it will be really very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: `$regex = New-Object Text.RegularExpressions.Regex '<TBD:comment.+?(".+?")(>.+?)<\/TBD:comment>', ('singleline', 'multiline')
$content = "<your html>"
foreach($m in $regex.Matches($content)) {
    # remove leading '<'
    $m.Groups[1].Value.Trim('"')
    $m.Groups[2].Value.Substring(1)
}`